# Meaning of "end in the sack" in this context (possibly nsfw?)

Tags: meaning, phrases, meaning-in-context

My girlfriend and I  were playing an erotic questions mobile game, and one of the questions was the following:

> Which day would you prefer to end in the sack?
>
> - New Year's Eve
> - My birthday
> - Christmas Eve
> - Mondays

The question was addressed to a woman. We have no clue what "in the sack" means here and so cannot proceed. English is not our native language, so we would be grateful for an explanation!

Comment: "In the sack" means "in bed".

Comment: More specifically, "to end in the sack" means "to end with having sex"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> #### In The Sack
>
> *informal*
>
> - In bed, used especially when referring to people having sex
>
> *He’s just trying to get you in the sack.*

([Macmillan Dictionary](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/in-the-sack))

Comment: Thanks! I googled for "end in the sack" as a whole phrase, so I missed this definition.

Answer (score -1):

Given the context, I would say it means **'in bed with your girlfriend, having sex.'**

Comment: Hmmm ... the question was addressed to a woman, right?  I guess she would maybe want to be in bed with her girlfriend ... but somehow I do not thing snowbird meant that...